# Azure pipeline error 'Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode.'

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines

I am installing IIS on a windows 10 Pro machine using power shell script.
I am using this [blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/may/25/automating-iis-feature-installation-with-powershell) to create the script.

The script installs IIS with following core.

```
# * Make sure you run this script from a Powershel Admin Prompt!
# * Make sure Powershell Execution Policy is bypassed to run these scripts:
# * YOU MAY HAVE TO RUN THIS COMMAND PRIOR TO RUNNING THIS SCRIPT!
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process

# To list all Windows Features: dism /online /Get-Features
# Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online 
# LIST All IIS FEATURES: 
# Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | where FeatureName -like 'IIS-*'

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServer
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-CommonHttpFeatures
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpErrors
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpRedirect
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationDevelopment
```

I have pipelined the task on DevOps:

[image]

Everything was working , but today when I started deployment , started getting the error

> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not 
>   available.
>   At C:\azagent\A1_work_temp\af294c00-d96a-4b04-b507-e2e3afcbee4f.ps1:12 char:1
>   + Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], PSInvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
>
> PowerShell exited with code '1'.

I have checked  `get-ExecutionPolicy` , which is `unrestricted` and  `$confirmpreference` set to `High`.

Why am I getting this error when it was working fine till day before?

Could this be due to windows updates ? How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Weird! May be it's prompting for some kind of child operation say expecting a reboot or something like that. Can you give a try by adding " -Force -Confirm:$false" at the end of each Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature command.

Comment: Hey @KrishnaG-MSFT, I just did a reboot and everything works fine now. Little weird for sure

Answer (score 3):

As the comment says: the error message indicates that one of your commands is trying to prompt user for confirmation. In case of `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature`, it's probably prompting for reboot.

Usually you can supress prompts by adding `-Force` and `-Confirm:$false` to Powershell commands.

Additinaly, `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` has [`-NoRestart` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/enable-windowsoptionalfeature?view=windowsserver2019-ps), which should prevent it from prompting for reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was the caused by passing `-debug` to the AzurePowerShell task as a script argument.
But the error message is inaccurate, it's showing errors at the place the command is called.

Azure pipeline task which has the same error:

```
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.serviceConnectionName }}'
      scriptType: 'FilePath'
      errorActionPreference: 'stop'
      azurePowerShellVersion: 'OtherVersion'
      preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '9.5.0'
      scriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/myScript.ps1'
      ScriptArguments: >-
        -location "xxx" 
        ... 
        -debug
```

My Script:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jew0Q.png)

The error was thrown at line 7 where the command `Get-AzResourceGroup -Name 'my-rg' -Location $location` is called.

Once the `-debug` argument is removed, the script is working.